# How to modify only one column value in Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Student> studentArray = new ArrayList<Student>();

studentArray.add(new Student("Nick", "18", "1st Street"));
studentArray.add(new Student("John", "22", "2st Street"));
studentArray.add(new Student("Anthony", "19", "3rd Street"));
```

How to modify 2nd row's address only?
I want to change 1st Street to 2nd Street, but I want to keep John and 22 same as before.

2nd row, 3rd item.

Comment: Not clear, you add constructor aka new Object, so do you want to change existing Object?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 rows.  I do not want to add new row.  I just want to change exiting row, but only one item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
studentArray.get(1).setAddress("new address");
```

However, this expects your students class to have `setAddress()` method, also note that 2nd element has index 1 (indexes are counted from zero)

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
studentArray.get(1).<setterOfLocationAtStudentClass>("some value");
```

Description:

`studentArray.get(1)` - getting the 2nd element because start is 0
`<setterOfLocationAtStudentClass>` - you should write your own setter method at Student for the field